# Xlsx or csv retrieve in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I have points data in `.xlsx` and I want to read and store them in `p` array in *Matlab*. These points are only *3D co-ordinates* of `x`,`y`,`z` such that having understood three columns and not prdfined rows. How I can retrieve them from `.xlsx` or `.csv` if I need fast retrieval as I tried to retrieve `.xlsx` and its response time is slow and returns an empty array. Possibly store them in transposed form and transpose it back.
[image: Scren Shot of my excel file]

**My Code: .Xls read**

```
 A = xlsread('data.xlsx')
```

**Output:**

```
A =

     []
```

**My Code: .CSV read**

```
 M = csvread('data.csv')
```

**Output:**

```
   Error using dlmread (line 139)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 2u, field 1u) ==> ;\n
Error in csvread (line 48)
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);
```

**Points Set 1:**

```
 -191.2442  187.7193    1.0000;
 -155.2995  152.6316    2.0000;
 -182.0276  104.6784    3.0000;
 -148.8479   84.7953    4.0000;
```

**Points Set 2:**

```
 -142.3963   83.6257    5.0000;
 -102.7650  133.9181    6.0000;
  -56.6820  164.3275    7.0000;
  -30.8756  124.5614    8.0000;
  -23.5023  118.7135   7.0000;
   -9.6774  110.5263   6.0000;
   26.2673   90.6433   5.0000;
  -42.8571   -6.4327   4.0000;
   10.5991    7.6023   3.0000;
```

**Points Set 3:**

```
  -73.2719   84.7953    9.0000;
 -137.7880   15.7895   10.0000;
  -92.6267  -30.9942    9.0000;
  -42.8571   19.2982    8.0000;
   41.0138  -15.7895   4.0000;
   71.4286  -41.5205   6.0000;
   90.7834  -14.6199   5.0000;
```

Comment: Is your column separator a `,`? Otherwise try using `M = dlmread(filename, '\t')` (with the right separator, example uses tap separator)

Comment: Yeah I also tried that, giving the error : `Error using dlmread (line 139)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 2u, field 1u) ==> ,187.7193,    1.0000;\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this slightly twisted one using `importdata` works for you -

```
C1 = importdata(file1) %%// file1 is your CSV filename
t1 = regexp(C1,'\s','Split')
t2 = horzcat(t1{:})
t2 = strrep(t2,';','')
M = cellfun(@str2num,reshape(t2(~strcmp(t2,'')),3,[])')
```

**Edit 1:** This case assumes you have a `CSV` file that has all the `Point Sets` clustered together but one by one **(without spaces between the `Point Sets` and their data and also between the end of  a `Point Set` and the declaration of the arrival of the next `Point Set`)**.

So, the input CSV file would look like this for the given data in the question -

```
Points Set 1:
 -191.2442  187.7193    1.0000;
 -155.2995  152.6316    2.0000;
 -182.0276  104.6784    3.0000;
 -148.8479   84.7953    4.0000;
Points Set 2:
 -142.3963   83.6257    5.0000;
 -102.7650  133.9181    6.0000;
  -56.6820  164.3275    7.0000;
  -30.8756  124.5614    8.0000;
  -23.5023  118.7135   7.0000;
   -9.6774  110.5263   6.0000;
   26.2673   90.6433   5.0000;
  -42.8571   -6.4327   4.0000;
   10.5991    7.6023   3.0000;
Points Set 3:
  -73.2719   84.7953    9.0000;
 -137.7880   15.7895   10.0000;
  -92.6267  -30.9942    9.0000;
  -42.8571   19.2982    8.0000;
   41.0138  -15.7895   4.0000;
   71.4286  -41.5205   6.0000;
   90.7834  -14.6199   5.0000;
```

Please note that the result from the codes would be a struct of arrays.

**Code**

```
C1 = importdata(file1) %%// file1 is your CSV filename
ind1 = cellfun(@isempty,strfind(C1,'Points'))

start_ind = find(~ind1)+1
s1 = find(~ind1)-1;
stop_ind = [s1(2:end) ; numel(ind1)]

for k = 1:numel(start_ind)
    data1 = C1(start_ind(k):stop_ind(k))
    t1 = regexp(data1,'\s','Split')
    t2 = strrep(horzcat(t1{:}),';','')
    t2 = t2(~strcmp(t2,''))
    array(k).data = cellfun(@str2num,reshape(t2,3,[])'); %%//'
end
```

Comment: It's retrieving in the from of strings but I need array. What about the functions `xlsread` and `csvread`

Comment: OK .. but it's retriving only one array, How i can make 3 different points set ?

Comment: @user3593525 I am assuming you have those three point sets as three separate files. If I am allowed to assume that way, you just need to change the file paths at the top of the code when using `importdata`. Would that work?

Comment: Yeah it works cool, but I want to read a complete data set and for every point, its difficuit to manage all files. May it is possible in on file with some identity?

Comment: @user3593525 So all the data from all the three points sets would come  under a single variable whose number of columns is 3 and number of rows (assuming the given data) would be 20(4+9+7)?

Comment: Obviously, it should giv separate arrays or likly to chose points by numbering of point sts.

Comment: I have chosen th `,xlsx` for that sake, How I can read from Excel ?

Comment: @user3593525 Check out **Edit 1**!

Comment: @Dicakar I didnt understand the format, also couldn't retrive correct results.

Comment: @user3593525 Why not upload what you have CSV or Excel file somewhere and link it here, so that the confusions are gotten rid of?

Comment: I have captured the image and points are already given in the post, Kindly check.

Comment: @user3593525 Would it be okay if the code gives you three variables - x,y and z such that x holds the data of the first column from the excel sheet, y  holds the second column and z holds the third column?

Comment: YEah I think its OK, we can `cat()` them to store in a single array. I actually needs a seprate array according to every points set.

Comment: @user3593525 In the meantime, could you try converting that excel file into the older version which uses extension of `xls`, i.e. make another excel file named `data.xls`  and then try to read the data with this - `A = xlsread('data.xls')` and then see if `A` is still empty?

Comment: Yeah it is also empty. @Divakar

Comment: U have any other idea which can help me to store data points externally and retive them in array?

Comment: @user3593525 Yes! Let's just go back to our `importdata` approach and let me clarify it to the best of my verbose methods. Hope this settles it finally! Check out **Edit 1** once more.

Comment: `array` is updated for every new point set, may it would b written as a function using `varargout` ? by the way, you are mind blowing dude. :)

Comment: @user3593525 `array(1).data`, `array(2).data` and `array(3).data` are what you need. You are right, my mind is almost blown :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51941/discussion-between-user3593525-and-divakar)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the row separator `;\n` (semicolon + new line). I don't know any function understand this format. Using `texstscan` is probably the best option:

```
fid=fopen(...)
M=cell2mat(textscan(line,'%f,%f,%f;\n'));
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: I'm only using `;` however your soultion is giving error `Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.`

Comment: Did you replace the `...` with your filename?

Comment: Yeah, its `data.csv` and `data.xlsx` but giving the same error